# Check if SPListItem already exists

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a powershell script which imports data from a csv file, and then uploads it into a list.

That works fine, but if the item already exists, for example if the item is already imported, the script still runs and adds all the same data again as seperate items.

Is there a way to get the script to check if that item already exists in the list, if exist, update item, if not add item

I have the 2 scripts that adds and updates, i just need to know how to add the If, else statements

Like the If exists, else - statements from the batch scripting world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a CAML query to get the item' ID

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"YourField\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + YourCode+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

And then ask for it's "ows_ID" property, if its null, or nothing, then add the item, otherwhise, use batch update to update your item.

Comment: not sure i understand, i got 2 seperate powershell scripts, now i just need to check wether the item exists, and then make one of them run depending on wether the item exists or not

Comment: Ok, lets take a breath ;) Have You used CAML querys? If not, not to worry, take a look at this awesome article which explains how to use CAML query and PowerShell scripts: http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/12/05/SharePoint-CAML-and-PowerShell.aspx It's ok, you don't need to rid off your PS Scripts ;) Just need to learn how to mix up those tools.

Comment: i have not use CAML querys before, ill look into it :) thanks alot :D